# checking strings for specific date format

Tags: c#, list, date, filter

I have a `List<String>Times` and unfortunately some of the data inside contains dates like `1-Apr` or `26-Mar`. I know how to implement a for-loop to parse every data but what do I use exactly to check for the dates.

Inside `List<String>Times`, There's data on times like 11:30am , 12:00mn etc etc

Comment: so what are you actually looking for, the dates, or the times?

Comment: `if (DateTime.TryParseExact("11:30am", "hh:mmtt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.AssumeLocal, out var dt))`

Comment: sorry for being inaccurate, im looking for the times actually . and all the data is in string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is a way to tell the diffrence between dates and times, it's not the best way but in this case it could do the job:

```
Boolean isTime(String input){
    return input.contains(":");
}

void iterateList(){
    foreach(String s in Times){
        if(isTime(s)){
            //handle time
        } else {
            //handle dates
        }
    }
}
```

i dont know if this is what you're looking for so i could be wrong

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`DateTime.ParseExact`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss.aspx).

Depending on your input text, you choose the appropriate [format string](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings). For example for `1-Apr`, you use `"d-MMM"`:

```
DateTime date = DateTime.ParseExact("1-Apr", "d-MMM", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Note that you have to use the appropriate culture for your case. The example is with `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture`.